# "#" (comments) is SLURM job submissions

Tags: slurm

The question is related to the article [Introducing SLURM by Princeton Research Computing](https://researchcomputing.princeton.edu/education/online-tutorials/getting-started/introducing-slurm).

For instance,

```
#SBATCH --job-name=slurm-test    # create a short name for your job
```

`SBATCH` after the first `#` will be executed, and `create` after the second `#` will be regarded as a comment. Is this because there is a space in the second `#`? I typically regard `#` as a comment. But in some cases, it does get executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#` is for comment in bash, so you should not run `my_job.slurm` with `./my_job.slurm` or `bash ./my_job.slurm` because all things after `#` will be ignored.

But when you run it with `sbatch`, it will recognize comments beginning with SBATCH as parameters.

https://support.ceci-hpc.be/doc/_contents/QuickStart/SubmittingJobs/SlurmTutorial.html#creating-a-job

> A submission script is a shell script, e.g. a Bash script, whose **comments**, if they are **prefixed with SBATCH**, are understood by Slurm as parameters describing resource requests and other submissions options.

Comment: Thanks. So, if I use # sbatch, is it the same as #sbatch? Sorry that it is not convenient to test at this moment.

Answer (score 2):

When submitting a SLURM job using `sbatch`, any line in the job script starting with the exact string `#SBATCH` will be taken as a special processing directive for the job scheduler.

The string `#SBATCH` is called a "magic cookie" and has to occur as the first thing on the line, with no space between `#` and `SBATCH`.

Such lines are, if executed by `bash` or other common POSIX shell, taken as comments and are completely ignored.

It is not clear from the [`sbatch` documentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html) that a *further* `#` on that line is universally supported as a way of giving a comment to the current `#SBATCH` line.  If a `#SBATCH` line needs a comment, it is common practice to provide an ordinary  comment on the line above the line, as in

```
### Job name
#SBATCH --job-name=MYJOB
```

(the triple `###` means nothing special apart from making the comment stand out a bit).

See also:

- [The SLURM article in the HPC Wiki](https://hpc-wiki.info/hpc/SLURM)